# AS3 Class inherit from sprite doesn't draw

Tags: actionscript-3

I just created a class: `ClassA extends Sprite`
then I created another class: `ClassB extends ClassA`

From my understanding `ClassB` is also a `Sprite`.

but when i try something like adding a displayable object(like a bitmap) as a child in `ClassB`, it doesn't draw anything.

but if I extends `ClassB` directly from `Sprite` (like `ClassB extends Sprite`), then the object will be drawn.

So my question is why the object is not drawn in a 2-level inheritance? How can I fix the problem or is there anything missing?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I just made a test, and I'm correctly displaying a Bitmap from a 2-level inheritance of Sprite. Can you show us your faulty code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your assumption is correct and should work.  You must have some semantic mistake.  Maybe youre not calling super in the constructor of each class and youre adding the instance of ClassB on the display chain.

example:

```
---------------classA--------------------

public class ClassA extends Sprite{
    function ClassA(){
        super();
    }
}

---------------classB--------------------

public class ClassB extends ClassA{
    function ClassB(){
        super();
    }
}

-----------------usage------------------

var foo:ClassB = new ClassB();    //new instance
addChild(foo);  //add to display hierarchy
foo.addChild( yourBitmap );    //add your bitmap to the new instance, can be done

-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was asking about. The problem is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

There could be something wrong in your code. Otherwise in principle yes you are right ClassB is Sprite in truth. I have tested this and it works accordingly.

```
      package
     {
        import flash.display.Sprite;

         public class ClassA extends Sprite
         {
             public function ClassA()
             {
                 super();
             }
          }
      }


       public classB extends ClassA
       {
           [Embed(source="image.png")]
           private var Image:Class;
           public classB()
           {
               addChild(new Image);
           }
       }


        // Add ClassB to display List

        public class Main extends Sprite
        {
           public  function Main()
           {
              super(); addChild(new ClassB);
           }
        }
```

See if you can go through your code. I am certain there is logical error. If you are loading an image then see if there is IO/Security  errors by registering a listeners. It could be that  image is not being loaded as a result of that. Thanks

Comment: you're not calling super() in classB.  Also class names should be Uppercased.  Instance names should be lowercased.